# Write a SQL query to find the average of the published articles in perticular daterange

Tags: mysql, sql

My database contains 2 columns journal_title, article_title & publish_year.
I have written the below query and it returned this result:

```sql
SELECT journal_title, publish_year, COUNT(article_title) AS total_article 
FROM dumm_table 
GROUP BY journal_title, publish_year 
ORDER BY journal_title, publish_year
```

[image]

Now I need to write a query to find the average number of articles published by a journal over the years.

Example:
For the journal "**Biophysical chemistry**", total **315** articles have been published in **9 years**(1991, 1992, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 199, 1999 & 2007).
So the average number of articles published by this journal over the 9 years is: 315 / 9 = 35

Same for the journal "**Biophysical journal**", total **54** articles have been published in **2 years**(2006 & 2007).
So the average number of articles published by this journal over the 2 years is: 54 / 2 = 27

Please help me to write the SQL to get the result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok I must retract that, I had missed your SQL query at the top as it is not in a code block. However, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a
question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT journal_title, AVG(num_articles) as avg_num_articles
FROM (
    SELECT journal_title, publish_year, COUNT(article_title) AS total_article  
    FROM dumm_table 
    GROUP BY journal_title, publish_year 
    ORDER BY journal_title, publish_year
) t
GROUP BY journal_title
```